# Oracle "Cannot update to NULL"

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-update, notnull

I have this query on Oracle 10g:

```
UPDATE "SCHEMA1"."CELLS_GLIST" 
SET ("GLIST_VALUE_ID", "USER_ID", "SESSION_ID") = (
    SELECT "GLIST_VALUE_ID", 1 AS "USER_ID", 123456 AS "SESSION_ID"
    FROM "SCHEMA1"."GLISTS_VALUES_UOR"
    WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
    AND ("GLIST_ID"=67)
    AND ("GLIST_VALUE_DESC" = (
        SELECT "GLIST_VALUE_DESC"
        FROM "BMAN_TP1"."GLISTS_VALUES_UOR"
        WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
        AND ("GLIST_VALUE_ID"="CELLS_GLIST"."GLIST_VALUE_ID")
    ))
)
WHERE EXISTS (......)
```

It keeps saying **ORA-01407: cannot update ("SCHEMA1"."CELLS_GLIST"."SESSION_ID") to NULL**

"SESSION_ID" is obviously *Not Nullable*, but I'm actually passing a value to that field, so I do not understand the problem.

Comment: Does your select even return a record?

Comment: Are you really wanting to update every row in your table?

Comment: @DCookie No, actually I've stripped out a `WHERE EXIST` part

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you for your suggestion. The query operates a conversion between two "Global Lists" so, if a conversion value is not found in the destination list, the subquery should actually return a NULL, and a (NULL, 1, 123456) triple should be written. Probably, with this syntax, a (NULL, NULL, NULL) triple is returned and the exception is raised. How can I modify the syntax to achieve my wanted result?

Comment: You should at least put a "WHERE ..." at the end of your update statement to indicate you've thought about it.

Comment: Done. Sincerly, I don't understand how I  would confuse future readers. Number of selected records is not a key point of the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this query also to work:

```
UPDATE "BMAN_TP1"."CELLS_GLIST" 
SET "GLIST_VALUE_ID" = (
    SELECT "GLIST_VALUE_ID"
    FROM "BMAN_TP1"."GLISTS_VALUES_UOR"
    WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
    AND ("GLIST_ID"=67)
    AND ("GLIST_VALUE_DESC" = (
        SELECT "GLIST_VALUE_DESC"
        FROM "BMAN_TP1"."GLISTS_VALUES_UOR"
        WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
        AND ("GLIST_VALUE_ID"="CELLS_GLIST"."GLIST_VALUE_ID")
        ))
    ),
    "SESSION_ID" = 123456,
    "USER_ID" = 1
WHERE EXISTS (......)
```

But, it performs really really fast... I doubt I'm missing something...

Comment: That was it?? You want to update all session/user ID's to a dummy value? Remember, your original subquery seemed not to have returned any records, so you might as well just drop the table :)

Comment: @LukasEder No, they are not dummy values. Actually, `USER_ID` identifies currently logged user that executes the query, while `SESSION_ID` is randomly generated by my application to uniquely identify the session. Additionally, where the conversion value is found for the destination `GLIST`, the cell is written with new ID. If it's not, the cell is blanked.

Comment: @LukasEder And no, it does not apply to all my table! Remember: as I stated above, this piece of query lacks of a `WHERE EXISTS` part that I stripped out in this question.

Comment: Added missing `WHERE EXISTS` part

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, I read that you seem to want to write a default record to your target table, in case the subquery doesn't return any records. So the correct way to phrase your query would be using a [`MERGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm) statement as such:

```
MERGE INTO "SCHEMA1"."CELLS_GLIST" dst
USING (
  -- rephrase your subquery here. This is your "merge data source". The number
  -- of records returned in this subquery will correspond to the number of
  -- affected records in dst
) src
ON (
  -- the missing exists condition here. Everytime this condition matches a record
  -- between dst and src, an UPDATE is performed. Otherwise, an INSERT is
  -- performed
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET dst."GLIST_VALUE_ID" = src."GLIST_VALUE_ID"
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ("GLIST_VALUE_ID", "USER_ID", "SESSION_ID")
  VALUES (NULL, 1, 123456);
```

This is just to give you an idea. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve in detail, so I omitted the subqueries and conditions