# Complex UPDATE query in SQL Server 2008, rewrite from Oracle 10g

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I need to re-write the following *Oracle 10g* query to work in *SQL Server 2008*

It's an update query, where some field are retrieved from a `SELECT` and some are given (from code).

```
UPDATE "BMAN_SQL"."CELLS_GLIST" 
   SET ("GLIST_ID", "GLIST_VALUE_ID") = (

                                         SELECT "GLIST_ID", "GLIST_VAL_ID"
                                         FROM "BMAN_SQL"."GLISTS_VAL_UOR"
                                         WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
                                         AND ("GLIST_CODE"='X')

                                        ), 
       "SESSION_ID" = 1553245736,
       "USER_ID" = 13

WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )
```

Note that I **need** to use the `UPDATE SET ... WHERE EXIST ...` structure for compatibility with Oracle (query are automatically built by a QueryBuilder class for each specific DBMS).

I also **cannot** write:

```
UPDATE "BMAN_SQL"."CELLS_GLIST" 
   SET ("GLIST_ID", "GLIST_VALUE_ID", "SESSION_ID", "USER_ID") = (

                        SELECT "GLIST_ID", "GLIST_VAL_ID", 1553245736, 13
                        FROM "BMAN_SQL"."GLISTS_VAL_UOR"
                        WHERE ("UOR_ID"=3)
                        AND ("GLIST_CODE"='X')

       )

WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )
```

because (as per this old thread [Oracle "Cannot update to NULL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523213/oracle-cannot-update-to-null)) it returns an error if the `SELECT` does not fetch any record.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join update query in this case. Please see syntax below. `<Your condition here>` Replace this section with your join condition here.

```
UPDATE m 
SET 
    GLIST_ID = r.GLIST_ID
    ,GLIST_VALUE_ID = r.GLIST_VAL_ID
    , SESSION_ID= 1553245736
    , USER_ID = 13
from BMAN_SQL.CELLS_GLIST m
inner join BMAN_SQL.GLISTS_VAL_UOR r on <Your condition here>
WHERE 
r.UOR_ID=3 AND (r.GLIST_CODE='X') AND
EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )
```

**EDIT**

```
UPDATE BMAN_SQL.CELLS_GLIST 
SET 
GLIST_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 GLIST_ID FROM BMAN_SQL.GLISTS_VAL_UOR WHERE (UOR_ID=3) AND (GLIST_CODE='X'))
,GLIST_VALUE_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 GLIST_VAL_ID FROM BMAN_SQL.GLISTS_VAL_UOR WHERE (UOR_ID=3) AND (GLIST_CODE='X'))
,SESSION_ID = 1553245736
,USER_ID = 13
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )
```

Comment: your edit matches my needs more... But I'm wondering if `UPDATE SET FLD1 = VAL1, FLD2 = VAL2` would be the same as `UPDATE SET (FLD1, FLD2) = (VAL1, VAL2)`. It should, teoretically...

Comment: @Teejay: Yes, it would work same unless there is a change in query. Also I am expecting Sql server will optimize this query to run only once but not sure. You can check its execution plan.